# return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: python, django, django-users

I'm currently working on a small project using Python's Django framework technology. 
I tried to extend the native user model to create 2 types of users
And I did it like so:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default = False,)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default = False,)

#Particularly for Teacher:
class Teacher(User):
    is_teacher = True
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username']

#Particularly for Student:  
class Student(User):
    is_student = True
    reg_num = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username']
```

whenever I try to create and save either of the users like so from my shell

```
from django.db import models
from hire.models import Teacher

j = Teacher(username =  'teacherAubrey', email  = 'learn@aubrey.com', 
password = 'squarerootof69is8sum')
j.save()
```

**return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)**
**IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: hire_teacher.email**

*hire is the app name* 
*teacher is the name of the class I'm accessing*
*email is the attribute*

What do you figure to be the problems here ?

I intentionally did not declare username, password and email instances in my Teacher and Student classes because I'm inheriting them from the User class

**Update**
I've been able to solve the above problem. 
Now, I want it to be impossible to call the `.save()` for the Student class when the reg_num field is empty.
And I want the use of `.save()` to be impossible for both Users (classes) when the password is not provided.
Thanks

Comment: (1) The error mentions `hire_teacher` but that's nowhere in the code. Are you sure you've included everything relevant? (2) `'email' or 'username'` is always going to evaluate to just `'email'`. I don't think you understand how `or` works. (3) Since you're inheriting from `User` I don't see why you would also add `user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)` (4) I don't think creating a field like `is_student = models.BooleanField(default = False,)` and then overriding it with a static value will work correctly (5) Under `Student` you have `is_employer = True` instead of `is_student`

Comment: I have corrected the typographical error. I made those mistakes while typing the code here on stackoverflow, it isn't like that in my text editor.

Comment: And Yes I've included every necessary module

Comment: I removed user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...), re-run my migration. Yet same problem.

Comment: I tested your setup, and it works fine for me. I was able to create new `Teacher` and `Student` instances and save them. Did you set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? Maybe there is something else important that causes the error that you didn't include in your question?

Comment: Yes I used the AUTH_USER_MODEL = hire.User

Comment: **Update**
I've been able to solve the above problem. 
Now, I want it to be impossible to call the `.save()` for the Student class when the reg_num field is empty.
And I want the use of `.save()` to be impossible for both Users (classes) when the password is not provided.
Thanks